# ObjC: +[NSObject isSubclassOfClass:] gives incorrect failure

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I have an iOS static library which defines an `NSOperation` base class that clients should subclass to add their own logic to: `@interface BaseClass : NSOperation`
- Clients register their subclasses with a manager: `-[OperationManagerClass registerClass:forType:]`
- In the manager, I want to enforce that you must register a subclass of `BaseClass` not just `NSOperation`

Okay, so seems like asserting `+isSubclassOfClass:` should get the job done. But... it doesn't.

```
@implementation OperationManagerClass

- (void)registerClass:(Class)aClass forType:(NSString *)type
{
    NSAssert([aClass isSubclassOfClass:[BaseClass class]);

    self.registeredClasses[type] = aClass;
}

@end
```

The assert is always `NO`, even when passed `BaseClass`.

What about traveling higher up the class hierarchy? `NSOperation` and `NSObject` both respond `YES`!

```
(lldb) p (BOOL)[aClass isSubclassOfClass:[BaseClass class]]
(BOOL) $0 = NO
(lldb) po aClass
BaseClass
(lldb) p (BOOL)[aClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSOperation class]]
(BOOL) $2 = YES
(lldb) p (BOOL)[aClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSObject class]]
(BOOL) $3 = YES
```

Mind you, the consumers of the base operation class are subclassing in the iOS application project, and `OperationManagerClass` and `BaseClass` are in an included static library. Why do I think this might have something to do with `isSubclassOfClass:` being wrong? Because of the following...

*Still in libSharedStuff.a*

```
@implementation OperationManagerClass

- (void)registerClass:(Class)aClass forType:(NSString *)type
{
    // Obviously OperationManagerClass.m cannot #import "OutsideClass.h"
    NSAssert([aClass isSubclassOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"OutsideClass");

    self.registeredClasses[type] = aClass;
}

@end
```

*In application target*

```
@interface OutsideClass : NSOperation
@end

@interface OutsideClassSubA : OutsideClass
@end
```

... yields the following results when `OutsideClassSubA` is passed in:

```
(lldb) p (BOOL)[aClass isSubclassOfClass:[OutsideClass class]]
(BOOL) $0 = YES
(lldb) po aClass
OutsideClassSubA
(lldb) p (BOOL)[aClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSOperation class]]
(BOOL) $2 = YES
(lldb) p (BOOL)[aClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSObject class]]
(BOOL) $3 = YES
```

**What's going on here? Why does `+isSubclassOfClass:` give the wrong answer? How can I enforce that the `aClass` parameter must be a subclass of my `BaseClass`?**

---

*Edit:*
I realized the example I posted works fine after pulling the pieces into a separate Xcode workspace. I've [posted the toy source code from above](https://github.com/evandelaney/StackOverflow-19883472) with a twist I left out of my original description.

I actually have *two* static libraries (`libSharedStuff.a` and `libHelperSharedStuff.a`). The application target links with `libSharedStuff.a`, and the unit test target depends on the application target as well as links `libHelperSharedStuff.a`. When `BaseClass.m` is a member of *both* static library targets, then `+isSubclassOfClass:` will fail in unit test assertions. Specifically, it fails when I pass `MockBaseClass`, which is a subclass of `BaseClass` that is part of the unit test target.

All of this is illustrated in the project linked above.

Comment: How about a workaround:
`NSAssert([aClass.superclass isKindOfClass[BaseClass class]])`

Comment: *fidgets nervously* eeeh... I thought about that, but that is enforcing something slightly different than what I really want. Also, I think it would be `NSAssert([aClass superclass] == [BaseClass class])` but don't hold me to that! :-)

Comment: Of course, you could check if *any* of the superclasses is the right type. That would give you the logic equivalent to checking for superclass. If `[NSObject isSubclassOfClass:]` refuses to play nicely, you might implement your own this way :)

Comment: Do you mean that Baseclass.m is in both static library projects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I explain in the edit of my question, I'm including `BaseClass.m` in both static libraries `libSharedStuff.a` and `libHelperSharedStuff.a`. The main application target links against `libSharedStuff.a` and the unit test target links with `libHelperSharedStuff.a`. This means that when the `.xctest` bundle is injected into my application at runtime, the `BaseClass` symbol is  defined twice

(*Maybe? Is that possible? What actually happens in the runtime?*).

I seems that in my unit test target `MockSubclassOfBaseClass` inherits from the `BaseClass` symbol in `libHelperSharedStuff.a`, whereas in my application target `SubclassOfBaseClass` inherits from the `BaseClass` symbol in `libSharedStuff.a`. If that's the case, then it makes sense why `+isSublcassOfClass:` responds `NO` when `MockSubclassOfBaseClass` is passed in!

Any answers that clarifies, confirms, or gives better insight that I've got the right idea here are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to have two classes with the same name loaded in an app. If so, the runtime should complain (check the debugger console and the device console in the Organizer).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the static library is actually causing the symbols to be linked in correctly. My immediate guess would be that the static lib–provided classes passed as aClass are actually Nil at runtime, and therefore returning 0 to any messages sent it.

One way to ensure this is to make a constructor function which uses them:

```
__attribute__((constructor)) static void EnsureClassesAreLoaded(void) {
    [BaseClass self];
}
```

Weak-linked classes can be a bit tricksy.

Comment: Hm. Interesting thought. Not sure I've got enough expertise here, but `nm libSharedStuff.a` does print `U _OBJC_CLASS_$_BaseClass`, `S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BaseClass` and `(BaseClass.o):` ... again, I'm out of my comfort zone w/ nm, but I think this means the static library is good?

Comment: This isn't about the static library, but about ensuring that the static library is actually linked into your app.  If your app doesn't have a hard reference to any symbol in the library, the library may not be linked at all.

Comment: bbum: Further to your point, it can be linked in and not bring all its symbols in, can it not? Although perhaps this only applies to categories, now that I think of it; dead code stripping, more or less?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cocoa pods make sure you didn't link all the pods to the testing target.

That fixed the issue for me.